# Need visa for brother to travel with me to UK

Tags: indian-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds, standard-visitor-visas, cultural-awareness

I am an Indian doctor working in the Gulf. I have applied for a visa to attend a post graduate exam. My employer has provided me with a letter for the UK Consulate for assistance with providing a visa, and I can prove that I have financial ties here, so I will definitely leave the UK at the end of my visit.

Can I provide my bank statements on behalf of my brother so that he can get a visa as well?

I need him to travel with me as I can't travel alone. He is a graduate, currently working part-time so he does not have an employment certificate. He also does not have significant savings.

How can I convince them to grant him a visa as well?

Comment: Why does your brother need to travel with you?

Comment: Social reasons, basically. In my family, women preferably don't travel alone, especially if there is no one they know in the place they are visiting. So to avoid problems with the folks, I need my brother to get a visa to accompany me. At this point all I want to do is just be able to go and attend my exam with the least amount of trouble at home. Any suggestions?

Comment: UK immigration is not likely to accept that. If you want no trouble, leave your brother at home.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you think his visa application will not be accepted?

Comment: You can prove you will come back, but it will be difficult to prove your brother will come back which will be a sticking point. Can your brother prove emphatically that he will return back but your statements prove otherwise.

Comment: What about my mum and younger brother?  He's 11 years old. We will travel together, tour a bit, then return. My mum's not working, she's supported financially by my dad. He's employed here full-time. My youngest brother is studying in a school here. Are they more likely to be approved? I know that this is a sentiment that may not be well understood by many, and I respect your opinions, but if my folks insist that I don't travel unaccompanied, I'd rather find a way to do it that way if I can. Any thoughts on my question?

Answer (score 4):

In commentary you explained "`women preferably don't travel alone`" and therefore you need your brother to accompany you so that you can sit an exam.

I expect that you will have difficulty establishing a premise for your brother to accompany you to the UK for the purposes of providing family supervision.  The point being that people who have attained a physician's qualification will visit the UK and sit their examination as an independent adult.

Granted that customs and traditions influence the way that people explain their rationale for visiting the UK, the decision-makers are not obliged to treat this type of premise as substantial; this is especially true if the applicant(s) would not qualify in their own right. You pointed out that your brother requires 3rd party sponsorship, and what this amalgamates to is that he has neither premise nor means to qualify independently.

What makes it worse is that you have already applied for your entry clearance and were in a position at that time to know that your family would place constraints on your travel.  But based upon your narrative, he did not apply along with you. This would raise a big-time question mark for the decision-maker and it would be very difficult to see it resolved in your favour.

**What about my mum and younger brother?**

The same reasoning applies here.  If you require family supervision in order to travel, you would have known about it earlier and explained it when you made your application.  When they see applications arrive from your family members on a premise that you cannot travel alone, they would be entitled to suspect (if not conclude outright) that you had not disclosed your circumstances in a transparent manner.

Comment: I did mention in my application that I would like to travel with my brother, but I did not give the reason for it. I am planning now to apply separately for my mother and youngest brother instead. She can prove ties to our country by showing that my father works here. She can also prove that she has financial  savings here. In her application, and that of my youngest brother, we are mentioning that all three so of will travel together. Will that be likely to succeed? I am not going for PLAB,I am going for a postgraduate exam, I have no plans to work in the UK at present.